# Refused to execute script from '*'

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

At `https://rawgit.com/UserName/master/file.json` (dummy URL) I am hosting a `JSON` file.
The **exact** JSON file being hosted it this:

```
[
  {
     "name":"Europe",
     "id":1
  },

  {
     "name":"USA",
     "id":2
  }
]
```

And when I try to obtain this via AngularJS:

```
return{

fetchData : function(remoteDataId){
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  var url = 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/Username/master/' + remoteDataId;
  $http.get(url, { cache:true }).then
    (
        function(resp){
            deferred.resolve(resp.data)
        },
        function(err){
            deferred.reject();
        }
    )

    return deferred.promise;
  }
};
```

I get this error : R`efused to execute script from 'https://rawgit.com/UserName/master/file.json?callback=angular.callbacks._3' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.`

What is wrong here? According to JSLint my `JSON` is valid. Should I add anything to the `.json` file?

Comment: The error message looks pretty clear to me. Even if the browser would run the code it wouldn't work, because it's just a JSON file. JSONP requires a **JavaScript** response.

Comment: You seem to be fetching JSON but treating it like JSONP. I don't know angular, but it seems you'd just want to get rid of the `?callback=JSON_CALLBACK`

Comment: @Pointy So what should I do? i tried wrapping it in a function name. But I am failing at that. Can you guide me?

Comment: @cookiemonster I did try getting rid of it. Does not work.

Comment: Your file should be a JavaScript file so that your server responds with the proper MIME type. The contents should look like what you've got now, except wrapped in a function call: `JSON_CALLBACK( ... )`. There must be a global function somewhere on your page called "JSON_CALLBACK" (unless Angular takes care of that;'I don't know Angular).

Comment: @Pointy Thanks a lot sir! I did manage to solve it somehow.

Answer (score 2):

I changed `$http.jsonp()` to `$http.get()`. It works even though it is a cross origin request.

Comment: If the server receiving the request has the correct cross origin resource sharing headers then yes - it definitely should. Moreover this is by far the preferred way to perform cross origin requests. See http://enable-cors.org/

Comment: Also, your promise code has the deferred anti pattern. You're creating an excess deferred object for no reason - don't do that.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Thanks for your insight sir. But I am creating just one deferred object. Look at the edit sir

Comment: You should be creating exactly zero deferred objects - you can simply `return $http.get(...`.

Comment: What I did not get it. Can you post an answer a bit more in detail if you dont mind.

Comment: `fetchData : function(remoteDataId){ var url = "..."; return $http.get(url, {cache: true }).then(function(d){ return d.data; }); }`

Comment: But that is not what we do in Angular right? But I still tried it and it did not work. Thanks for letting me know it is an anti pattern.

Comment: The code is inside a service, and the data being returned is resolved by the UI router. So I need async way of handling it. Hence the defer.  Am I still wrong?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @KevinBrechbühl this is the OP answering his own question and what worked for him - please be more careful in your flags. OP - $http.get already returns a promise, so wrapping it in another promise is redundant.

Comment: Why am I being called OP?

Comment: @user3834536 OP is short for "Original Poster" as in - the person who has asked the question.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum yeah you are right. Was too fast, because he asked another question in the answer...